# how to delete an administrator on yosemite

Tags: user-account, accounts

My roommate moved out. He and i are both administrators on my iMac. How can I delete him? 
I have tried going into system preferences, users & groups, but even after I unlock it I cannot make any changes to his account.

Comment: Is he still logged in?

Comment: Also a screenshot of "Users & Groups" after unlocking would help

Comment: If you know his password log in the log out.

Answer (score 1):

I got this hint from here http://applehelpwriter.com/2013/05/09/how-to-log-out-another-user-without-logging-in/

Log out the user or any other processes that is still running owned by the user you wish to delete.

> 1. Open up Activity Monitor (/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app)
> 2. Use the drop down menu in the Task bar to change the menu to ‘Other User Processes’  (note: you can use ‘All Processes’ in the menu if you
>      wish, but that is less safe as it makes it possible to accidentally
>      click on your own user process in step 4 below!).
> 3. In the filter bar, type loginwindow.
> 4. From the list of users that show up, for each one that you wish to log out:
>
>    - click on its row in the Activity Monitor pane to highlight the process
>    - press the ‘Quit Process’ icon in the Task bar above
>    - from the resulting dialogue window, click ‘Force Quit’
>    - supply an Admin password if requested.